# One npm module for different instruction set

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a project developed on **node.js**. 
Development takes place on two different machines: one bit x32, on the other - x64. The problem is that some npm-modules have conflicts if they run in different environments.

For example, **dNode**. I installed it on a machine with 32 bit, but on the computer with the bit shch this module throws an error.
I can somehow control this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the dependencies to your `package.json` then use `npm install` on the target machine. If the module has special arch features, it will install it during the `npm install`. Do not ship the module with your codebase.

Comment: Frankly, did not understand. Can be more detailed instructions?

Comment: when you put your application on a new machine, you should not copy the `node_module` folder, but run `npm install instead`. It will install the modules for the targeted platform (x32 or x64).

Comment: So, every time a new car to reinstall modules? And how to work through the GIT team?

Comment: add `node_modules` to your `.gitignore` file and ask your team to run `npm install` after they cloned the project.

Comment: Got it. Terribly uncomfortable scheme. Apparently, there is no other solution.

Comment: This scheme is the same than with many languages/platform: java with ant, maven or gradle, ruby with gems, python with setuptools, C with make, etc.